# How to display Chinese/Japanese/Korean fonts in pdf (from QTextDocument)

Tags: qt, pdf, chinese-locale, qtextdocument

I am having issues getting Chinese/Japanese/Korean characters to appear in a .pdf generated from a QTextDocument. The chars appear fine in the QTextDocument widget just fine.  But, then I output the document to a .pdf, they C/J/K chars do not appear.
In my search for an solution, I see lots of suggestions to install the font families.  But, if the chars are appearing in the widget on-screen, then does that not mean the font families are installed correctly.  So, perhaps my question is more to do with installing font families vs. displaying the chars.  I'm not sure at this point.

Sample code:

```
  QTextDocument* pDocument = mpTextEdit->document();
  QTextCursor cursor(pDocument);

  QFont defaultFont("Calibri", 12);
  pDocument->setDefaultFont(defaultFont);
  QString str = "<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
  str += "<br/>";
  str += QString("名称不能为空。");
  str += "<br/>";
  str += "ABC";
  str += "</p>";
  pDocument->setHtml(str);

// Print to .pdf
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::PrinterResolution);
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer.setOutputFileName("c:/temp/foo.pdf");
printer.setFontEmbeddingEnabled(true);
pDocument->setPageSize(printer.pageRect().size()); 
pDocument->print(&printer);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Mike Dembroge